# Compute Reed-Solomon Error Correction Codewords from a QR-Code Encoding

Tags: go, package, qr-code, error-correction, reed-solomon

for a little project I'm asked to come up with a little QR-Code encoder in Go. After successfully completing the analysing and encoding part, I'm now trying to wrap my head around the error correction using the following package:

https://github.com/klauspost/reedsolomon

Essentially, I don't understand how to structure the data and parity shards inputs in connection with a specific QR-Code version and its specifications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is basically the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [research.swtch.com/field](http://research.swtch.com/field) and [research.swtch.com/qart](http://research.swtch.com/qart).